# Login with mechanize python. String returned

Tags: python, cookies, mechanize-python

Im trying to make a script to access a webpage. It loads the first page, finds the login form, fill it and submit. The website works just like facebook, if you have the cookie already you are redirected to your feed list, otherwise to the login page.
But as a response I dont get another page, a simply get a string like that:

s1:1MEqkcRcZQ7x6adaszkZUQyRFRhCfXz1z:c2c8d18f12f50ab3e8daA1cf80a0d8b9f64e9d6684b8eb064dd76892d6134cde:1646683

Its like 4 strings separated with a ":". The first I dont know what is. The second is the username, the third is my hashed password (I suppose), and the last one is my user id.
Making a test in FF, I find out that is a Javascript problem, if you dont have Javascript enabled on your browser you get that string after login.

Here's my  code>

```
    import mechanize
    import urllib
    import cookielib

    # Browser
    br = mechanize.Browser()

    # Cookie Jar
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)

    # Browser options
    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_gzip(True)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True  )
    br.set_handle_robots(False)

    # Follows refresh 0 but not hangs on refresh > 0
    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

    # Want debugging messages?
    br.set_debug_http(True)
    br.set_debug_redirects(True)
    br.set_debug_responses(True)

    # User-Agent (this is cheating, ok?)
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.3')]

    # If the protected site didn't receive the authentication data you would
    wallet = 'username'
    password = 'password'

    response = br.open('https://www.example.com/')
    #html = response.read()

    # Show the source
    #print html
    # or
    #print br.response().read()

    # Show the html title
    print br.title()
    #print response.read()


    # Show the response headers
    #print response.info()
    # or
    #print br.response().info()

    # Show the available forms
    for form in br.forms():
        print "Form name:", form.name
        print form

    # Select the login form
    br.select_form(nr=2)

    # Let's login
    #br.form['op'] = 'login'
    br.form['login'] = wallet
    br.form['password'] = password
    response1 = br.submit()

    print response1
    print response1.read()
    print "#######################"
    cookie = cookielib.Cookie(version=0, name='PON', value="response1.read()", expires=365, port=None, port_specified=False, domain='https://www.example.com/', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=False, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=True, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HttpOnly': False}, rfc2109=False)
    cj.set_cookie(cookie)
    response = br.open(https://www.example.com/)
```

Because I dont know what the string is, I figured it was a Cookie, so I tried to put in my Cookiejar, and tried to br.open(url) again, but it returns always the login page.
I have to replicate what the website's javascript does in python, but so far I'm stucked.
Any thoughts? I already tried to read the source code of the website, but I didnt find the script that is causing me trouble. Its probably inside the head tag right? I dont know.

Comment: You've tagged 3 languages but only show one, which is relevant and which are not?

Comment: try adding referer header to same domain manually.

Comment: I dont remember adding php as a tag. Only javascript and python

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
My mistake was to try set a Cookie with all the string. Each part of the string was a different cookie. The name of the cookies I got using the chrome extension "Live HTTP Headers".